# How to ask "¿hay?" In English?

Tags: translation

The other day i was giving an English lesson to some friends :p one of them asked me for a snack, i gave her a frozen yogurt pop... then another friend's son asked me" there is, there is?? Trying to translate "hay hay??" I was so ashamed about not having another for him and i did not pay attention about the way he asked.

Is there a way to say it that short?

Well i guess the correct way to ask it is " is there still any?  Or do you still have any?

Am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean from Spanish to English.

> [hay](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/hay)
>   impersonal verb
>   1. (to exist)
>   a. there is (singular)
>   *Hay un hombre mirándote.—There is a man looking at you.*
>   b. there are (plural)
>   *¿Hay pimientos en la nevera?—Are there any peppers in the fridge?*

The child asked "¿Hay?", which would be the question form of "there are": *Are there?* This is not impossible, since we know he's talking about the [frozen yoghurt pops](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=frozen+%22yogurt+pop%22&rlz=1C2AOHY_enIT708IT708&biw=1366&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG6arktfXPAhWEVxoKHcZnCwQQ_AUIBigB) (*plural*).

Other possibilities are: "Are there any left?" or simply "Any left?"

Comment: Or "any more?" or even just "more?" would be a direct translation. *¿Hay?* by itself is not a complete sentence, but it's fine since we know the context.  In the same way "More?" is perfectly understood in  context, and is similarly something a child would say when asking for a treat.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure what is meant by "hay?". *Hay* is dried grass. *Hey!* is an exclamation used to attract attention. One common way to phrase the question is "Is there any more?", or if you know that there is some more, you could ask "May I have some more?" It is a little impertinent for an adult to ask either of these questions, but a child would be forgiven.

[Cambridge Dictionary: hay](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hay)

[Cambridge Dictionary: hey](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hey)

Comment: If you're unsure what the question is asking, you should  ask the author for clarification in a comment (preferably before you try to answer it). If it's unclear to you, there are probably other folks that would benefit from the question being clarified.